# NodeJS Buffer read bits from Bytes

Tags: node.js, binary

I have the following example buffers and trying to extract some data from this.

```
<Buffer 38 31 aa 5e>
<Buffer 1c b2 4e 5f>
<Buffer c4 c0 28 60>
<Buffer 04 7a 52 60>
<Buffer 14 17 cd 60>
```

The data is in the format

**Byte 1** - UTC nanosecond LS byte

**Byte 2** - UTC nanosecond

**Byte 3** - UTC nanosecond

**Byte 4** - bits 0-5 UTC nanosecond upper 6 bits, 6-7 raw bits for debugging

I get bit shifting when I need whole bytes together but never needed to concatenate this with bits of a byte too.  Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to read the values as a single int and then use [bitwise math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) to pull out the values.

```
// Read the value as little-endian since the least significant bytes are first.
var val = buf.readUInt32LE(0);

// Mask the last 2 bits out of the 32-bit value.
var nanoseconds = val & 0x3FFFFFFF;

// Mark just the final bits and convert to a boolean.
var bit6Set = !!(val & 0x40000000);
var bit7Set = !!(val & 0x80000000);
```

Comment: Oh neat, how do I get the raw bit values of the last two bits though?  Also I don't get the "& 0x3FFFFFFF" what operation does that perform?

Comment: It appears the last 2 bits are possibly not correct?  I think I need the raw values here?

Comment: @LeeArmstrong Updated the method to grab individual bits and added a link that will help explain the bitwise math I am doing.

Comment: Thanks, the link helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a better solution so I would like to share:

```
_getNode(bitIndex: number, id: Buffer) {
  const byte   = ~~(bitIndex / 8); // which byte to look at
  const bit    = bitIndex % 8;     // which bit within the byte to look at
  const idByte = id[byte];         // grab the byte from the buffer
  if (idByte & Math.pow(2, (7 - bit))) { do something here } // check that the bit is set
}
```

It's just a little clearer / more concise. Notice how we use natural log2 pattern to our advantage to check if the bit is set.

Comment: Just notice that operating on the buffer directly completely ignores endianness. This only works if you know all of your buffers are of the correct endianness.